# Generating PDF File

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java and looking for an easy way to generate a PDF file.

I need to populate the PDF with multiple tables having columns and rows.

Also be able to render text headers outside the tables.

Is there any open source library i can use for above purpose?

I did some research online and found some libraries. But the problem is that, am not able to find much documents on how to use those lib's.

The main purpose is to add tables in PDF and this lib should have proper documentation on how to do that!

Comment: Saw this question while opening my browser, I don't have much time to leave a detailed answer. But check out https://pdfbox.apache.org/ I've seen it used in a few projects.

Comment: Google for keywords: java pdf generate. Why use stackoverflow for the question google can answer?

Comment: See [help/on-topic], point #4: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try iText.

There's a book "iText in action" and lots of samples.
For instance, [here you can find a sample using tables](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=76)